# How can I display custom collada models in Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, collada

I have a set of reconstructed point cloud data (location + color) covering a large area of ground and I would like to display it in Google Earth.

Originally the data was in a .ply format, but I've converted it to Collada using [MeshLab](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/&ei=XpnsT5jXLcj30gGIx_i1BQ&usg=AFQjCNE7qGOhi_Zv3qdOTAChyun27nRNVQ) and tried to import it by modifying the KML file found [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/models). Google Earth gave an error about being unable to load the .dae file. I also attempted reconstructing a mesh from the point cloud data and loading that, but had no luck there either.

Does anyone have any experience/advice loading custom models into Google Earth? Are the .dae files exported by MeshLab not standard conforming, does Google Earth only support a subset of the Collada functionality, or is there another issue entirely?

I've posted a trimmed down version of the a sample .dae file [here](http://pastebin.com/yFb23B7E).

Edit: [full version](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B28_1J26fE1bTGdXWnN2Ynh2X28)[15M].

Comment: Can you post the sample file **with** the data in it? It's not useful to post a non-working file that can't be opened.

Comment: I didn't/don't believe the problem is with the data, but given as I don't know what the problem is, I've added it to the OP.

Comment: The ``<triangles>`` tag is empty. Is it like that in your file, or just the one you posted? It makes it a lot easier to debug if it's the complete file.

Comment: I imagine that is the result of converting point data to a collada format. A version of the data that has been converted to a mesh has a `<polylist>` tag and behaves with similar results.

Comment: Can you post the complete polylist file? Note that collada doesn't support point data

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with MeshLab in the past but for my data sets it has been a bit of an overkill and getting a .dae hasn't been the easiest

I have had better luck scripting sketchup to process point data to create models that will show up in google earth.  I'm only dealing with a few thousand points per model though.

there are a lot of plugin examples, a good place to start
http://forums.sketchucation.com/